# leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@420482c0 that was originally added here

Tags: android

I have the following error :

```
02-21 11:42:13.174: E/WindowManager(29845): Activity info.androidhive.tabsswipe.Party has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@420482c0 that was originally added here
02-21 11:42:13.174: E/WindowManager(29845): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity info.androidhive.tabsswipe.Party has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@420482c0 that was originally added here
02-21 11:42:13.174: E/WindowManager(29845):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:376)
02-21 11:42:13.174: E/WindowManager(29845):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:296)
02-21 11:42:13.174: E/WindowManager(29845):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:228)
02-21 11:42:13.174: E/WindowManager(29845):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:149)
02-21 11:42:13.174: E/WindowManager(29845):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:549)
02-21 11:42:13.174: E/WindowManager(29845):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:277)
02-21 11:42:13.174: E/WindowManager(29845):     at info.androidhive.tabsswipe.Party$LoadParties.onPreExecute(Party.java:120)
02-21 11:42:13.174: E/WindowManager(298
```

Can anyone help me? This is my code :

```
 package info.androidhive.tabsswipe;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import java.util.HashMap;

import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Party extends ListActivity {



    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Creating JSON Parser object
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> partyList;

    // url to get all products list
    private static String url = "http://192.168.1.6/politiciansnpolitics/appphp/parties.php" ;

    // JSON Node names
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_PARTY = "party";
    private static final String TAG_ID = "party_id";
    private static final String TAG_NAME = "party_name";
    private static final String TAG_PIC = "party_logo";

    // products JSONArray
    JSONArray party = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_party);

        Drawable rightArrow = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.worldmap2);


        // setting the opacity (alpha)
        rightArrow.setAlpha(100);

        // Hashmap for ListView
        partyList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        // Loading products in Background Thread
        new LoadParties().execute();

        // Get listview
        ListView lv = getListView();

        // on seleting single product
        // launching Edit Product Screen
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String party_id = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.id)).getText().toString();

                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Party_Desc.class);
                // sending pid to next activity
                in.putExtra(TAG_ID, party_id);

                // starting new activity and expecting some response back
                startActivityForResult(in, 100);
            }
        });

    }

    // Response from Edit Product Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // if result code 100
        if (resultCode == 100) {
            // if result code 100 is received
            // means user edited/deleted product
            // reload this screen again
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    }

    /**
     * Background Async Task to Load all product by making HTTP Request
     * */
    class LoadParties extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
         * */
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Party.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading parties. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting All products from url
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
             StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
          .detectDiskReads().detectDiskWrites().detectNetwork() // StrictMode is most commonly used to catch accidental disk or network access on the application's main thread
          .penaltyLog().build());

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            // getting JSON string from URL
            JSONObject json = jParser.makeHttpRequest(url, "GET", params);

            // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
            Log.d("All Products: ", json.toString());

            try {
                // Checking for SUCCESS TAG
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // products found
                    // Getting Array of Products
                    party = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PARTY);

                    // looping through All Products
                    for (int i = 0; i <party.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = party.getJSONObject(i);

                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        String id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                        // creating new HashMap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        // adding each child node to HashMap <span class="vf7210h94y" id="vf7210h94y_22">key</span> => value
                        map.put(TAG_ID, id);
                        map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                        // adding HashList to ArrayList
                        partyList.add(map);
                    }
                } else {
                    // no products found
                    // Launch Add New product Activity
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),TopRatedFragment.class);
                    // Closing all previous activities
                    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
         * **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            // updating UI from Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    /**
                     * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
                     * */
                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter( Party.this,partyList,R.layout.list_item, new String[] { TAG_ID,
                                    TAG_NAME},
                            new int[] { R.id.id, R.id.name });
                    // updating listview
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }
            });

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: When does this occur?

Comment: This error means: you did not get rid of a dialog

Comment: runOnUiThread inside onPostExecute is redundant because onPostExecute is executed on the UI Thread

Comment: after on pre execute..it closes the app

Comment: try like this in onPostExecute. if (pDialog.isShowing()) { pDialog.dismiss(); pDialog.cancel();}

Comment: @user3336646, have you tried what i suggested, whether it worked or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Window leaked error comes when some function tries to access the activity while its in background!,

So make sure you terminate your dialog when the activity goes to background.

In your case, add this to your activity.

```
@Override
public void onPause() {
super.onPause();
   if(pDialog != null){
       pDialog.dismiss();
   }
}
```

Comment: 02-21 17:21:19.801: W/dalvikvm(7768): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41856438)
02-21 17:21:19.871: E/AndroidRuntime(7768): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
02-21 17:21:19.871: E/AndroidRuntime(7768): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-21 17:21:19.871: E/AndroidRuntime(7768):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)now getting new error

Comment: Declare your adapter globally, then initialize it in the oncreate and then update it in the onPostExecute. Please check your listview implementation, its not right.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you should try using your application context instead of Activity here:

```
        ...
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Party.this);
        ...
```